# Rename File in Foundry Export

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

Is there an option to rename the file when exporting a dataset to external server using the new Foundry Export?

https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-connection/export-overview/

In the legacy export tasks we do have option to rename the file in the YAML, but is there similar solution with the new export as well? (Not renaming the file in transform when writing output but in export config itself)

Comment: Sounds like a feature request to the Connectors Team. You could rename the files in the last transforms before the export, as a workaround.

Comment: Yes. I have already implemented the same. But just wanted to check if there is a direct way.

Comment: I think we are in the same boat. Who doesn't love re-implementations with less features... -.-